# How to pass value from Dob Component to Amount component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-services

**amountcomponent.component.ts**

```
import { Component,Input,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'appchild',
    templateUrl: './amountcomponent.component.html'


})
export class AmountComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() greetMessage: string ;


    onKey(event: any) {
        console.log(event.target.value)

    }
    ngOnInit(){

    }


}
```

**amountcomponent.html**

```
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
<h2>{{greetMessage}}</h2>
```

**dobcomponent.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {AmountComponent} from "./amountcomponent.component";




@Component({

    templateUrl: './dobcomponent.component.html'

})

export class DoBComponent {

    public quantity:any;

    childmessage : string = "I am passed from Parent to child component"

    onquantity(event: any) {
        this.quantity = event.target.value
        console.log(this.quantity)

    }
```

}

**dobcomponent.html**

```
<input (keyup)="onquantity($event)">
<appchild [greetMessage]="childmessage"></appchild>
```

How to pass value from Dob Component to Amount component. i dont know how to pass it. so please help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an Output. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#declaring-input-and-output-properties

---

(Amount Component = child)

**amountcomponent.html**

```
<input #amountInput (keyup)="onKey(amountInput.value)">
<h2>{{greetMessage}}</h2>
```

**amountcomponent.component.ts**

```
export class AmountComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() greetMessage: string;
    @Output() amountChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

    onKey(amount: string) {
        console.log(amount)
        this.amountChange.emit(amount);
    }
}
```

---

(Dob component = parent)

**dobcomponent.html**

```
<input (keyup)="onquantity($event)">
<appchild [greetMessage]="childmessage" 
          (amountChange)="onAmountChange($event)"></appchild>
```

**dobcomponent.component.ts**

```
export class DoBComponent {
    public quantity:any;
    childmessage : string = "I am passed from Parent to child component"

    onquantity(event: any) {
        this.quantity = event.target.value
        console.log(this.quantity)
    }

    onAmountChange(amount: string) {
        console.log("new amount is", amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: not able to pass the value ..(childmessage : string = "I am passed from Parent to child component") is display in dob component .html only